# function to remove square brackets from dictionaries value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
{"john":["name"]}
```

How could i get rid of square brackets of value in it, so it looks like this:

```
{"john":"name"}
```

How could I write a function which would do that?

Comment: The value is a list, so this will replace it with the first item in the list: `Mydict[‘john’]=Mydict[‘john’][0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `dict comprehension` use indexing to access 1st element of the list

```
d = {k:v[0] for k,v in d.items()}
```